# Positive well-being or the absence of values: does it matter what to choose?

Tags: nihilism, pragmatism, values, normativity, value-theory

In his paper, “[If Nothing Matters](https://philarchive.org/rec/KAHINM)” (2016), Guy Kahane discusses evaluative nihilism, which is plainly described by him as:

> “Nothing is good or bad. All evaluative propositions are false.”

Prof. Michael Hauskeller wrote [a philosophical reflection](https://hauskeller.blogspot.com/2017/03/guy-kahane-on-why-and-when-it-matters.html?m=1) on this work. He claims that:

> “The problem with this argument is that it is hard to see in what way
> exactly mistaken belief in nihilism would be harmful. Remember that
> nihilism itself is supposed to be not only not harmful: it does not
> make the slightest difference for how we experience the world. If
> things did matter objectively and suddenly stopped mattering
> objectively, or did not matter and then suddenly started to matter, in
> neither case would we be able to tell the difference. The world as we
> know it would remain unchanged. (This alone should be sufficient to
> reject the notion of objective value: following William James’s
> excellent pragmatist principle that there can *be* no difference
> anywhere that doesn’t *make* a difference elsewhere,[[2]](https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=2391584212436941572#_ftn3) the claim
> that certain things matter objectively is simply meaningless.)” (italics original)

But what does he mean by “objectively matter”?

In the same article, he says:

> “This is, then, what people mean when they say that nothing matters:
> that nothing matters *objectively*. Things may still matter *subjectively*
> (i.e., we find something worth doing) but if they don’t matter
> objectively (i.e., it *really* is worth doing), then they don’t really
> matter at all. That nothing matters objectively Kahane takes to mean
> that the universe is “devoid of value”… The view that nothing matters
> can therefore be understood as a form of *evaluative nihilism*.“ (italics original)

Prof. Nadeem J. Z. Hussain explains in his article “[Error Theory and Fictionalism](https://philarchive.org/go.pl?id=HUSETA&proxyId=&u=https%3A%2F%2Fphilpapers.org%2Farchive%2FHUSETA.pdf)” that

> “If reality is as the sciences claim, then it is evaluatively and
> normatively neutral”:  “The universe, to simplify somewhat, is made up
> of elementary particles in a void with properties like charge or
> charm. Despite these evocative names, such properties are evaluatively
> neutral. In other words, saying that an electron has positive charge
> is not *ipso facto* a positive assessment; it is not saying that there
> is something good about being this way. Neither is it a normative
> assessment; it is not saying that the electron should be this way. All
> the properties that physics and, supposedly, the rest of the sciences
> ever mention are similarly neither evaluative nor normative… Once on
> this path, the grand conclusion that everything is without value and
> that there is nothing that one should do in life can seem inevitable.” (italics original)

As one can see, William James’s pragmatist principle and what sciences tell us give us strongly support evaluative nihilism. But where does it leave us?
As prof. Hauskeller says,

> “Generally speaking, then, nothing follows from evaluative nihilism.
> What matters to us will continue to matter to us, whether or not it
> *objectively* matters. Perhaps, if nihilism is true, we have no good
> reason to pursue whatever it is that we are pursuing in life, but the
> point is that we have no good reason *not* to pursue it either. Things
> are just the same as ever. Nihilism has, as Kahane says, “no normative
> implications. It cannot make the world bad or worse, or give anyone
> reasons to do or feel anything – or, for that matter, *not* to do or
> feel something. (…) The truth of nihilism, the total absence of all
> value, makes no normative difference.” (8)” (italics original)

However, my observation is that evaluative nihilism leads to a series of paradoxical statements:

1. The goodness is not needed.
2. It is not good that the goodness is not needed.
3. The goodness of the claim "it is not good that the goodness is not needed" is not needed.
4. It is not good that the goodness of that claim is not needed.
   To solve this chain of statements that can, in theory, continue indefinitely, we can say that

1. Nothing is good or bad
2. But the goodness isn’t needed anywhere

Although it may seem that no positive statement can follow from evaluative nihilism because on this view, there is a kind of symmetry between objectively good and bad things. But nevertheless, under evaluative nihilism, neither goodness nor badness is needed by anyone.

So, if one were to compare the inherent goodness of any well-being under evaluative nihilism and well-being (if evaluative nihilism is false), regardless of its positive, negative, or neutral nature, then that both hold equal weight. This means that under evaluative nihilism, which posits that all evaluative propositions are false, our current well-being is always enough and sufficient for us.

I asked artificial intelligence to assign this statement a letter s, a, b, c, d, e or f, where s represents a highly plausible statement and f is it’s opposite. The corrected version of it, which you can see in the previous paragraph, ended up in the s-tier.

So, it is enough that evaluative nihilism cannot make the world bad or worse, or give anyone reasons to do or feel anything, values and reasons are simply not needed by anyone. One can only need that if his well-being is somehow insufficient and there is a better alternative. But, again, this doesn’t make any sense if all evaluative propositions are false.

Comment: Under evaluative nihilism, our current well-being is *objectively* "enough and sufficient" and also "not enough and insufficient". Better to say, those categories are objectively meaningless. But it says nothing as to what is "enough and sufficient" *for us*. There is nothing paradoxical about your listed claims once you take into account that they are not "for us". They only sound paradoxical due to habitual substitution of familiar meanings for intended detached ones. This is why Hauskeller says that "nothing follows from evaluative nihilism", nothing that matters *to us*.

Comment: For small values of 'really'.

Comment: @Conifold I agree with your point that this doesn’t dictate what is “enough and sufficient” for us on a subjective level.
However, I would like to clarify my proposition. When I say our current well-being is always “enough and sufficient” under evaluative nihilism, I’m not making an evaluative judgment. Rather, I’m suggesting that in a world where all evaluative propositions are false, we don’t need reality to be good or bad in any objective sense. Our current state of well-being, regardless of its positive, negative, or neutral nature, holds equal weight to any other state of well-being.

Comment: @Conifold In this context, the terms “enough” and “sufficient” are not used as evaluative judgments, but rather to express the idea that under evaluative nihilism, there’s no objective standard that our well-being could fail to meet. Therefore, it can’t be objectively “not enough” or “insufficient”. This doesn’t mean that our well-being is objectively “enough” or “sufficient” in the sense of meeting some positive standard; rather, these evaluative terms simply don’t apply in an objective sense under evaluative nihilism.